# What to do with what I've learned when writing my research proposal?

Tags: publications, journals, statement-of-purpose, early-career

During the time to prepare for my application to applying to grad school, I have learned a lot of new knowledge. They are from various sources: scientific papers from insiders in the field, blog posts from them or other individuals, articles explaining the ideas for popular audience, Wikipedia, YouTube, etc. While they help me a lot to understand what the field is so that I can write a good research proposal, after having one I have basically nothing to do with them, except to answer my friends' question: "So, what do you do?", which I can only provide a small fraction of what I really know and want to say.

I think the knowledge has a better potential to help me go further in my career, so I am thinking to turn it into a real article/paper. There will be an international conference in my country in which my field is one topic of it and my furthest goal is to write the article good enough so that I can submit a poster in there. The deadline to submit is before I starting grad school so I guess that I will have to write it by myself. Although I always want to put my best effort to every product I make, I don't want to spend more than one month on writing this in order to move on to my next project. Popular readers will be my audience of course.

**Q**: The first and foremost question is: is this worth? Are there other alternative ways to do with what I've learned? If making it as an article is indeed worth to do, I still don't know how to maximize the benefit that it will bring to me. I have some more things to consider:

- **Language**: What language should I use? If I write it in English, I can reach more readers and hope that I will find grant easier. However if I write in my native language, I would be the first one to write detailly about this and therefore having an advantage of being the first one, though I admit I don't know what to do next with this advantage in this stage of my career.
- **Place to publish**: Where should I publish this article? Of course I can always post it in my blog, but can it be published elsewhere? If I should write in English, can you suggest some journals/magazines that will accept my work? If it's in my native language, I have two options of where to submit and I don't know which one is better. The first one is an old reputable magazine among researchers in my country. It's a kind of dicussion board where topic can range from introducing new discovery or science news to critics about government policy in science. The other one is a new young but promising science journal that available in both languages, founded by a young researcher. Its focus is narrower, only introduction of actual research of my country researchers in hard science/technology.

Thank you so much for your time to reading this far.

Answer (score 2):

Having learnt something new does not mean that you can publish a research article. You need some new research to publish. So my answer to the question in the title is:

**Use your new knowledge to do research.**

If you still hold on to the idea of publishing something, you need to think hard about 1. a venue to publish and 2. what is it that makes your text publishable. If you can write a really good overview for some audience and can find a venue that may fit, you may try (but in fact, it is pretty hard and next to impossible to write a good overview when you just entered a field, this is something for more senior people).

Comment: But comparing to people who is not in my field, I do have something to say, right?

Comment: Sure, you may have something to say. But it's not clear if an academic publisher may want to publish it. Any academic journal has a description of its scope on its webpage and usually this says something like "This journal published original research in...". Put differently: Why should an academic publisher the right venue for what you have to say and not, for example, a blog post?

Comment: but these are not academic journals, in the sense that only original research is published. For what I know, these are magazines, and their scopes are for creating a forum for researchers come from any field. I also absolutely submitting a blog post to them, I just say that at the very least, I can post it on my blog.

Answer (score -2):

Research is always precious. Never ask a question like "Is this research useful?" ... You never know what you might hit upon in future. So, always maintain the copies of the journal articles and book chapters you read during the development of your dissertation or research paper. These days, inter-disciplinary research is becoming more and more popular. You may need to reckon or revisit your works anytime, anywhere. So, don't be disheartened. Instead, get yourself a cabinet where you can keep the hard copies of all the materials you read and analysis. You can also store electronic copies of relevant readings in a Cloud-based folder. One of the easiest ways is perhaps to cite and save all the articles you read on Google Scholar.

Comment: I can't see how this answer answers my question